# Automatic text colour change dependent on a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I make it so that when a value is equal to 0, the color of some text changes?

Comment: You have to check if the value is 0 and set the color of the text

Comment: Yes you absolutely can.

Answer (score 1):

You can, here is a simple solution (you can set multiple values). If the input is empty the text will be black. If you type something else than 0, 1 or 2 the text will be green.

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<p id="text">Some text</p>
```

```
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let text = document.getElementById("text");

input.oninput = function() {
  switch (input.value){
      case "0":
        text.style.color = "red";
      break;
      case "1":
        text.style.color = "pink";
      break;
      case "2":
        text.style.color = "blue";
      break;
      default:
        text.style.color = "green";
  }
}
```